# POST request body fails to get to PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, http, php5, apache-2.4

*I've seen the following issue on Apache 2.2/PHP 5.3 and on Apache 2.4/PHP 5.4*

I have encountered an rare issue where POST requests (small, under 1k) to a web server seem to be getting truncated before they reach the PHP service that will act on the data.  I have not been able to reproduce the issue myself, so I am only working on evidence gathered from logs.  In each case, I receive a request with a valid non-zero Content-length header but no body.

I've dumped a variety of information about the calling agent and I don't see any pattern. The broken requests come from a variety of browsers and source ips, and for any given ip I see plenty of valid requests around the occasional broken request.

I've tried using pecl_http's getRequestBody() and file_get_contents("php://input") and neither returns any data in this case.

I've also temporarily enabled mod_dumpio, and in the case of an offending transaction, I see an entry where it attempts to buffer the request body:

```
mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [readbytes-blocking] 288 readbytes
```

which would normally be followed by the actual buffering of the data, like:

```
mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 288 bytes
mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): (the post data)
```

But in the case where I encounter the problem, I don't see these entries, there is a notable delay of SEVERAL SECONDS on that apache process, and then instead I see several more instances of:

```
mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [readbytes-blocking] 288 readbytes
mod_dumpio: dumpio_in - 70014
```

And intermingled with these repeated read attempts, I see evidence of a PHP thread executing on the malformed request and producing a response.

It seems from the [HTTP protocol 4.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html) that the body of a request MUST match the content-length in order for the request to be valid, so I'm struggling to understand how the requests in question are making it to PHP.

I should also mention that the content-type in this case is being provided as application/x-www-form-urlencoded, even though the data sent is raw json.  Since I'm reading the data directly from the stream, I don't expect it is related to my issue, but it bears mentioning.

I don't want to blindly compare content-length to strlen($content) in PHP, but I'm running out of options for how to further diagnose the problem.  Any help with how to fix this situation OR gather further valuable debugging information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: readbytes-blocking would seem to indicate that the remainder of the POST body was not available, and that the request is blocking waiting for it.  Are you behind any sort of load balancer / firewall that could be interfering?  I'd probably suggest you down a level, and capture some traffic with tcpdump.  See if the entire request is making it to the server.

Comment: i am behind amazon elb w/ ssl terminated at the load balancer. please note that '-blocking' shows up for all getbytes & readline calls from dumpio, even on successful calls... i believe those are just synchronous calls, but not necessarily 'blocked'.  it does seem that the content is never arriving, or not completely arriving, though.  do you agree that if the post body is not fully received the request should fail before reaching php?

Comment: the 70014 message corresponds to an internal apache error for unexpected EOF, which makes some sense, but the fact that this log message is received (repeatedly) intermingled with PHP processing is puzzling. shouldn't apache have returned a 500 at that point, instead of passing an empty payload to PHP?